# How to get difference between two dates in netsuite?

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I m new to netsuite ,i have to find difference between two dates in netsuite.
How can i get the difference of two dates  in netsuite through scripts.help me,Thanks.

Comment: What value do you want, days? Hours? Months?

Comment: I want days and months.

Comment: How do you get the dates (user input? JSON? format?), what have you tried?

Answer (score 6):

### (I) Get the Difference of Two Date Fields Using an SQL Expression

1. Navigate to Customization > Lists, Records, & Fields > Entity Fields > New
2. Create the Custom Fields

**Custom Field 1.**

> Label = Date Created
>   ID: datecreated
>   Type: Date
>   Store Value: True
>   Applies To: Customer
>   Display > Subtab: Main

**Custom Field 2.**

> Label: Date Closed
>   ID: dateclosed
>   Type: Date
>   Store Value: True
>   Applies To: Customer
>   Display > Subtab: Main

**Custom Field 3.**

> Label: Days Open
>   Type: Date
>   Store Value: False
>   Applies To: Customer
>   Display > Subtab: Main
>   Validation and Defaulting > Formula: T
>   Formula field: `{dateclosed}-{datecreated}`

3. Pull up any Customer record > Fill out the custom fields.

For example:

Date Created = **9/1/2014**
Date Closed = **9/3/2014**

4. Click Save.
5. Days Open field should show the value of 2.

### (II) Calculate the Difference between a Date/Time field and a Date field Using Formula

The following formula will give you the difference in days. You can add this to the results tab of your saved search.

```
Formula(Numeric): ROUND({ID of date field}-{ID of other date field})
```

Note: Either field can be used for the date/time field value.

### (III) Using SuiteScript Code

```
function date_difference(date1, date2) {
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); // Get 1 day in milliseconds
    return diffDays;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a Text date ('01/01/2014') to a Date object with nlapiStringtoDate.

So basically you go

`timeDiff = Math.abs(nlapiStringtoDate(myDate).getTime() - (new Date).getTime())
 diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));`