# Netsuite Saved Search - Subtract difference between dates from case Formula(Date/Time) format

Tags: javascript, sql, netsuite

I'm wondering if there is a way to get the difference between custom date formulas on a saved search.

1st Formula (Date/Time):

```
CASE WHEN ({systemnotes.newvalue} = 'Pending Fulfillment') THEN {systemnotes.date} END
```

2nd Formula (Date/Time):

```
CASE WHEN ({systemnotes.newvalue} = 'Billed') THEN {systemnotes.date} END
```

Both these formulas give me the correct date I need, but now I need to figure out how to get the 2nd formula minus the 1st formula.

Is this possible?
I've tried:

Formula(Numeric):

```
((CASE WHEN ({systemnotes.newvalue} = 'Billed') THEN {systemnotes.date} END) - (CASE WHEN ({systemnotes.newvalue} = 'Pending Fulfillment') THEN {systemnotes.date} END))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get difference between two dates in netsuite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26334088/how-to-get-difference-between-two-dates-in-netsuite)

Comment: This should work: (CASE WHEN {systemnotes.newvalue}='Billed' THEN {systemnotes.date} END) - (CASE WHEN {systemnotes.newvalue}='Pending Fulfillment' THEN {systemnotes.date} END)